# Label disappears when connected to a IBOutlet Swift

Tags: swift

So I have a label it is just fine when it is in the storyboard but when it is in a simulator label disappears. The alpha is = 1 and it is not hidden.
    [storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IL1K.png)
    [simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFIQ9.png)

Comment: Probably the frame is wrong then.

Comment: @Sulthan what do you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraints where wrong. But thanks for the help.